# Is it possible that the thread notifying gets the lock and cycle again instead of the waiting thread

Tags: java, multithreading

If i have two threads - one is supposed to print odd numbers and the other even numbers - but the output should be in sequence.

For example:

```
T1 Thread 1 3 5 7 
T2 thread 2 4 6 8
```

The output should be

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
```

So, in order to communicate I can use wait notify, but my question is:
When T1 prints 1 and then notifies T2, it's waiting and hence has given up the lock.

Is it possible that T1 gets the cycle and locks again instead of T2?

Comment: Please post related code. It's hard to tell from your description.

Comment: This would be counterproductive. If T1 wants the lock for some task, it shouldn't release it in the first place. But this solely depends on the implementation of the scheduler: usually T2 would be the next in the (lock) queue. So if T? releases the lock, the next T in the queue will be activated.

Comment: lets think about a simple code from this link: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/inter-thread-communication-java/    now say T1 called this.wait() ..and has release the lock ofcourse, now T2 does its work and prints the first odd number 1 and says this.notify...now question is ..this.notify() will ensure that next lock on this is being taken by T1 or JVM can give the lock and cycle again to T2 as in its unpredictable